# Cannot delete data from Appengine Datastore due to error: "API call datastore_v3.Put() required more quota than is available"

Tags: google-app-engine

A Google Appengine application has reached the free resource limits regarding Datastore Stored Data. (All other quotas are OK). Hence I'm trying to delete data from the Datastore (on the [Datastore Adnmin page](https://appengine.google.com/datastore/admin)).

Only problem is, I cannot delete data because I get this error:

```
Delete Job Status
There was a problem kicking off the jobs. The error was:
The API call datastore_v3.Put() required more quota than is available.
```

How to break out from this vicious circle?

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait until the current billing day is over in order your datastore operations quotas to be reset, and the you will be able to delete entities.

Comment: Nice try, thanks, I've also seen this answer to a similar question. The thing is, the actual quota that has been exceeded is the 1 GBytes  of total 'Datastore Stored Data', this quota does not got reset.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the entities from your code and not the Datastore Admin?

Comment: No. What I have only tried to delete from the Datastore Viewer, that works but there I can only delete 20 records at a time. Currently I do not have an development environment set up for this application,  and I would prefer to save the time of setting up one. Actually I have created this app more than 4 years ago and now it has reached the 1 GBytes Data Storage Limit and been reported to be down due to this. Right now all I want to do is delete the data from the Datastore and get the app up and running.

Comment: Then I would propose adding a cron job that deletes batches of entities every x minutes. This way you will manage to delete your entities without having to do it manually for 20 entities each time.

Comment: Well, thanks for your concern. As I have mentioned, I try to minimize the efforts I spend on this issue as I'm working on many other projects. So here is what happening: I have spent a bug report to Google about the Datastore Admin/Delete entities feature. I have also learnt that this feature is very beta, it may work or may not work. Anyway, today I gave this "Datastore Admin/Delete feature" entities an other try and it seems to work. It has created a job with a description "Deleting all <entity name> entities" and that job is still running right now.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting this error after enabling billing,
you need to set a daily budget.
check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31693372/1942593