# The API call datastore_v3.Put() required more quota than is available

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

How to reset quota if **Datastore Write Operations** limit is reached ?
Any operation (both from admin console and from my code) on datastore reports the following error:

`The API call datastore_v3.Put() required more quota than is available.`

I have tried to disable application and wait for quota reset, but it did not work.
When the app is enabled, it produces a lot of tasks that in turn try to operate on datastore, what obviously consumes the quota.

Now, I have paused the task queues and will give another try waiting 24 hours.

Is it the right solution ?

Answer (score 11):

The quota is reset every 24h, so wait that time or enable billing. The quota won't reset by disabling and reenabling the application.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Another 24 h waiting helped, but it is worth to mention that app must be enabled and task queues paused (if tasks do any datastore operations).

Comment: an app must be enabled in any case if you want it to do something. its like turning the gas off the stovetop and expect the food to cook.

Comment: Oddly I have billing enabled yet I still got this error.  My billing history says I wasn't even charged so I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: it might take some time until it gets applied. cant really tell how long.

Answer (score 5):

You should assign a daily budget to your app even with billing enabled.
Maybe you forgot to do this.

goto cloud console, select project,
goto Compute > App Engine > Settings in the left side nav bar.
and set a daily budget.

[image: heres how that looks like]

Comment: i did this(set as 20$/day) but still i got above exception, is it happend to you?

Comment: No, I did a stress test with no budget and ran into this error. 
Then i set the budget and the test went on fine.